# textmate indent ruby code just left aligns it . how to properly indent ruby code in text mate

Tags: ruby, textmate

I am trying to format my code with textmate "indent" option . but textmate just left aligns everything .

What is the proper way to format ruby code in textmate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indenting Ruby code should actually indent it. Is the Ruby bundle selected for the file you are trying to indent?

Comment: sorry ..how do i select ruby bundle

Comment: It should be automatically selected for `.rb` files, but if you're editing a file with a different extension (or no extension, in the same of some scripts) it might not be automatically selected. The active bundle will be shown in the menu at the bottom of the window, next to where it says "Line" and "Column". It should say "Ruby".

Comment: that was it ..it was set to applescript for some wierd reason. thanks